# How to convert a BufferImage to bytes

Tags: java, swt

How do I convert a BufferImage to bytes?

I can't find useful help from JDK.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean BufferedImage?

eg :

BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\image\mypic.jpg"));   //javax.imageio.ImageIO

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( originalImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

//use proper exception handling

Answer (score 0):

BufferedImage to byte array:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
...

// O P E N
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream( 1000 );

// W R I T E
ImageIO.write( aBufferedImage, "jpeg" /* "png" "jpeg" ... format desired */,
           baos );

// C L O S E
baos.flush();
byte[] resultImageAsRawBytes = baos.toByteArray();

baos.close();
```

From: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/imageio.html#TOBYTES

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to convert an image into a 3D matrix of bytes, where each 2D cell corresponds to a pixel, with each pixel having 3 or 4 bytes, look no further [than here](https://github.com/skaushik92/File-Encryptor/blob/master/Source/ByteIO.java)!

On the other hand, if you are trying to read it in as you would any other file, just as a byte stream, use FileInputStream.

In either case, feel free to use my code on github!

https://github.com/skaushik92/File-Encryptor/blob/master/Source/ByteIO.java